# Pandas Dataframe- round multiple columns but enforce they sum to one

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

Lets say I have the following data frame where columns A, B, and C are weights, and the three must sum to one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0.56, 0.36, 0.08], [0.42, 0.13, 0.45]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

if we apply df.sum(axis=1), we see that indeed they all add up to one.  My goal is to have the same set of columns, but rounded to a single decimal (I need to bin my weights to fit in 10% buckets).  The problem is when we do this:

```
df.round(1).sum(axis=1)
```

We find that the first row sums to 1.1 (0.6 + 0.4 + 0.1), and the second row to 0.9 (0.4 + 0.1 + 0.4).  Is there a way in pandas to round while enforcing a "sums to 1" constraint on a number of columns?

Comment: I guess set the last weight to be 1 minus the sum of the other weights?

Comment: That could work, however I'd need to set the last non-zero weight (my actual problem has 20+ weights, 3-5 of which might be non-zero in a given row, and all zeros must stay zero).  Better might be to set a random non-zero value to the 1 minus the sum of the other weights, as then I am not biasing the later listed weights more.

Answer (score 2):

No.  There are various algorithms you can use to do this job, but they require detailed (i.e. iterate through the row) processing.

Perhaps the simplest is what we used to call "truncate-allocate".  Split each element of the row at the rounding point, keeping the truncated amount and the leftover (the part you use for rounding).  For instance, your first row above would leave us:

```
trunc = [0.50, 0.30, 0.00]
alloc = [0.06, 0.06, 0.08]
```

Now, observe that sum(trunc) is 0.8 ... there are 2 units to allocate.  Find the largest two elements of alloc; these are the last and either of the other two (likely determined by the last bit of the binary representation).  Add to those two elements:

```
trunc = [0.6, 0.3, 0.1]
```

Now it sums to 1.

Can you work with that?  Is it simple enough to solve your problem?  I know it's not a built-in function, but it's easy enough to understand, implement, and maintain.

Comment: I believe this will work quite well!  I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.